# Input Box not declared

Tags: vb.net, inputbox

The input box is "not declared".
Not sure exactly why this happening and I can't figure it out.

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Do
            f = InputBox("Inputs", "Enter The name Of the File.")
            If f = Nothing Or f = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Ooops!! No file name entered.")
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you didn't initialize the `f` variable:

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Do
        Dim f As String = InputBox("Inputs", "Enter The name Of the File.")
        ...
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Where would I enter that? Am I replacing f = InputBox("Inputs", "Enter The name Of the File.") with the code you just sent?

Comment: Exactly, just replace the one line with the line I posted.

Comment: I still got the same error message. Would you like to see all the code? I declare F at the start of the code as a string.

Comment: That would certainly be helpful. But I think it could be a different problem. Have you tried accessing `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox` directly? In which line does the error show up?

Comment: The error shows up in line 107. I tried accessing it directly and still got the same error. What's the best way of sending all the code?

Comment: `f = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Inputs", "Enter The name Of the File.")` is it this line? If `f` is initialized properly as a String, it appears that the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` namespace is not being referenced in your project. To  verify, take a look at the referenced namespaces (use View->Class View to access).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sFnYwuBr here's the entire code, I may have initialized it wrong. The first line you posted is the line where I am having issues

Comment: When I input the line you sent the error changes to 'Input Box' is not a member of 'Interaction'

Comment: Then it can't find the `InputBox` method. If you are using Visual Studio as your IDE, open the Class View to verify that `Microsoft.VisualBasic` is a referenced namespace. If it's not referenced, simply add it by going to Project->Add reference and ticking `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.

Comment: I went to class view and searched ```Microsoft.VisualBasic``` and it showed up but the code still doesn't work.

Comment: In this case I'm afraid I cannot help you with your issue. The most direct workaround would be to simply create a similar class which can then be even extended in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the form using `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor?

Other than that, this (more concise) code works as expected for me:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Do
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(InputBox("Inputs", "Enter the name of the file.")) Then Exit Do
        MessageBox.Show("Oops!! No file name entered.")
    Loop
End Sub
```

I'd check your references. And turn `Option Strict` *On* in any case to highlight any type/declaration issues.